# OpenAI ChatGPT API: CORS policy error when fetching data

Tags: javascript, openai-api, gpt-3

I am trying to write a simple JavaScript script which uses the ChatGPT API to ask a question and get a response.

However I am getting the following error message:

> "Access to fetch at
> 'https://api.chatgpt.com/answer?question=How%20are%20you?&api_key=sk-U3BPK...'
> from origin 'https://wordpress-......cloudwaysapps.com' has been
> blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your
> needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with
> CORS disabled."

I have enabled CORS headers server side in my hosting environment. But the error remains.

What is the reason for this issue and how can I fix this issue?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function askQuestion() {
      var question = document.getElementById("questionInput").value;
      var apiKey = document.getElementById("apiKey").value;
      // access chatgpt's API and pass in the question and API key as parameters
      fetch("https://api.chatgpt.com/answer?question=" + question + "&api_key=" + apiKey)
        .then(response => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Failed to fetch answer from API");
          }
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          // get the answer from the API response and display it in the textbox
          document.getElementById("answerBox").value = data.answer;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error fetching answer from API: ", error);
        });
    }

    function askFollowUpQuestion() {
      var followUpQuestion = document.getElementById("followUpQuestionInput").value;
      var apiKey = document.getElementById("apiKey").value;
      // access chatgpt's API and pass in the follow-up question and API key as parameters
      fetch("https://api.chatgpt.com/answer?question=" + followUpQuestion + "&api_key=" + apiKey)
        .then(response => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Failed to fetch answer from API");
          }
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          // get the answer from the API response and display it in the textbox
          document.getElementById("followUpAnswerBox").value = data.answer;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error fetching answer from API: ", error);
        });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="questionInput" placeholder="Enter your question here"></input>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="apiKey" placeholder="Enter your API key"></input>
  <br>
  <button onclick="askQuestion()">Ask</button>
  <br>
  <textarea id="answerBox" readonly></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="followUpQuestionInput" placeholder="Enter your follow-up question here"></input>
  <br>
  <button onclick="askFollowUpQuestion()">Ask Follow-up</button>
  <br>
  <textarea id="followUpAnswerBox" readonly></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where did you found `https://api.chatgpt.com`? Was this given by ChatGPT?

Comment: chatgpt definitely isn't officially supported on the openai api. It's on it's way though.

Comment: This isn't about ChatGPT's official API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE: 1 March 2023**

##### ChatGPT API (i.e., [Chat completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api)) is now available

As stated in the official [OpenAI blog](https://openai.com/blog/introducing-chatgpt-and-whisper-apis):

> **ChatGPT and Whisper models are now available on our API**, giving
> developers access to cutting-edge language (not just chat!) and
> speech-to-text capabilities. Through a series of system-wide
> optimizations, we’ve achieved 90% cost reduction for ChatGPT since
> December; we’re now passing through those savings to API users.
> Developers can now use our open-source Whisper large-v2 model in the
> API with much faster and cost-effective results. ChatGPT API users can
> expect continuous model improvements and the option to choose
> dedicated capacity for deeper control over the models. We’ve also
> listened closely to feedback from our developers and refined our API
> terms of service to better meet their needs.

See the [documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/chat).

---

##### ChatGPT API is not available yet

As stated on the official [OpenAI Twitter profile](https://twitter.com/OpenAI/status/1615160228366147585?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Etweet):

> We've learned a lot from the ChatGPT research preview and have been
> making important updates based on user feedback. **ChatGPT will be
> coming to our API and Microsoft's Azure OpenAI Service soon.**

Did you mean the GPT-3 API? If yes, then read the [documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/completion), see the list of all available [GPT-3 models](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3), and learn how to write the code using the [Completions endpoint](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions).

Comment: Please don't add the ChatGPT-api tag to questions that aren't about the official ChatGPT API.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should add it or not, since the original question was asked when the ChatGPT API was not available yet. :)

Comment: Tags only apply to the questions itself, so that'd be a "no" :D